# When I loop through an array in a list, I get "compiler is unable to type-check" error?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am making this app, and I have a log page where you can see the times you logged earlier. I looped through my array of logs, but when I try to display a value from the array in the loop I get "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" error. Here is the code for the logView swift file, there are more files and if you need them I can give you them, thanks.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LogView: View {
 
 @AppStorage("log") private var log: [String] = []
 
 var body: some View {
     List{
         ForEach(0...log.count, id: \.self) { index in
             if(index % 2 == 0 && index != 0){
                 NavigationLink{
                    Text("log detail view")
                 }label: {
                     HStack{
                         Text(index)
                         Spacer()
                         Text(index+1)
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     .navigationTitle("Log")
     .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
 }
}

struct LogView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
 static var previews: some View {
     RatingView(rating: .constant(3))
 }
}
```

Any and all tips are hugely appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think it’s the `if` statement that is the issue. Speaking of the if statement, why start a loop on zero and then specifically check if the value is not zero???

Comment: It´s not the `if` statement. You cannot store `[String]` in Appstorage and you are passing an `Int` to `Text` but it needs to be a `String`.

Comment: I also think the if statement is too complex. I think I'd do the check if the array is empty  before the ForEach, so the if within the ForEach, which will be used on each item, will be less complex.

Comment: In my array I have a date, and then a time. When you log them I did it that way so that I didn't have to deal with nested stuff, and if I don't start the loop at 0 I get a fatal error.

Comment: How can I fix this then?

Comment: You also need to change the end of the range to `<log.count` but it is not clear why you only want to show every second row instead of all rows so maybe it is a better way to handle the loop

Comment: @joakim-danielson he wants to use the array to have 2 different "types" of values, every first item should be a string with the date, every second item should be a string with the time. I recommended an alternative approach below in the answer.

Comment: @SebastianFox Maybe so but that is not in the question so this is all very unclear

Comment: yea, sorry, Im new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your last comments, I understand you need something like the following.
There is a struct **LogItem** that gets initialized with an id, the timestamp of the date/time of creation and a message. It also contains 2 functions to provide the the date and the time individually as formatted strings. Id, date and message are now var to match the Codable protocol.

In the **LogView**, there is a list nested within a NavigationView, so you can use NavigationLinks to a detail page (for that there is a new view **LogDetailedView**.

To add items to the array it is similar to the string array you used before, array has the function append, but instead of appending a string, you have to append an object of type LogItem.
To show how it works I also added a button that creates a new instance of LogItem with the message *"Log Message"*, it is just an example, you have to adjust it according to your needs.

```
//
//  Log.swift
//  Log
//
//  Created by Sebastian on 23.08.22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct LogItem: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var date = Date()
    var message: String
    
    func getDate() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    
    func getTime() -> String {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
        let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)
        return ("\(hour):\(minutes):\(seconds)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LogView()
    }
}

struct LogView: View {
    
    // Example text for new log events
    let exampleLogMessage = "Log Message"
    
    @AppStorage("logs") var logs: [LogItem] = []
    
    func addLogItem(message: String) {
        logs.append(LogItem(message: message))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            VStack(){
                List() {
                    ForEach(self.logs, id: \.self){ item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: LogDetailedView(logItem: item)) {
                            HStack() {
                                Text("\(item.getDate())")
                                Spacer()
                                Text("\(item.getTime())")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // This button is just an example how to add items to the array, please see also the function that gets called addLogItem(message: String)
                Button(action: {
                    self.addLogItem(message: exampleLogMessage)
                }) {
                    Text("Log Event")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LogDetailedView: View {
    
    var logItem: LogItem
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("Date: \(logItem.getDate())")
            Text("Time: \(logItem.getTime())")
            Text("Message: \(logItem.message)")
        }
    }
}
```

To use **@AppStorage** with a custom object **Array** must conform RawRepresentable, you achieve that with the following code/extension (just add it once somewhere in your project):

```
extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
              let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

And here are 2 screenshots (1. LogView - with the List of available logs; 2. LogDetailedView - with the log details (date, time and message):

[image: 1. LogView - with the List of available logs]

[image: 2. LogDetailedView - with the log details (date, time and message)]

Comment: Why not `let id = UUID()`? It's not necessary that `id` is a string and even a variable.

Comment: You are right, I changed it, I also changed it for time and date, in a log it shouldn't change once it is initialized.

Comment: Alright, first of all thanks, second of all: 1. I want the user to be able to click on one of the logs and it will pull up a detailed view with more info.  2. I was fiddling around and this seems so include the whole of my array for some reason or another, I don't really know why, but it works. 3. I want there to be a spacer between date and time in the log.

Comment: Also, if I used the struct, how would I add items to the log?

Comment: and could I do that method in appStorage?

Comment: I adjusted the answer according to the latest comments. 

You can add items in the same way like you did it before, use the append function from the array, instead of strings you have to add instances of LogItem. Either you create the instance of LogItem before or directly when appending to the array, I added a small example.

@AppStorage can be used, but you have to make some adjustments to Array (must conform to RawRepresentable) and the new struct LogItem (must conform to Codable), it is now part of the answer.

Comment: Sweet, this works great. Thanks so much for the help. Sorry that I am bad at swift